# How to use excel data to find period

Tags: excel, excel-formula, periodicity

I have three Excel columns of data from an experiment with a pendulum: time, angle displacement, and angular velocity. I was wondering if there is a way in Excel to calculate and then graph the period (and, if possible, display the function for the graph)... I realize it's kinda a dumb question. I'm still new at Excel. 
Thanks for any pointers u can give!

Comment: What do you mean by "graph the period"? It should be a single value for a simple pendulum.

Comment: If you have the formula for calculating the period then you can easily put that into a cell and drag down - then analyze the differences if any between values for the sources of error.

Comment: I need to graph the period because it changes between measurements; the graph of angle displacement over time change has a decreasing frequency over the 200 entries. I’m using the period formula separately; I want to compare the theory to the experimental. I I tried the Fourier series but it just told me it need a 2^n number of entries to work... :(

Answer (score 2):

In case the [`Analysis ToolPak`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/load-the-analysis-toolpak-in-excel-6a63e598-cd6d-42e3-9317-6b40ba1a66b4) is installed, one can use `Tools`->`Data Analysis`->`Fourier Analysis`. If the data is a superposition of harmonic functions (`sin`,`cos`), the corresponding frequencies (or inverse periods) will appear as peaks in the Fourier analysis.

Comment: Very nice.  It looks like I need to use =IMABS() on the resulting table of complex numbers.